# Make a window as background?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to set one window as a background. I mean that this window never will be in front of other windows. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Famous thought experiment: [*“What if two programs did this?”*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413) – which window would be the bottom-most one, then?

Comment: Except you could say the same about "Always On Top", and that exists.

Comment: Phoshi: Two windows that are »always on top« can overlap each other. See the link which deals exactly with this – someone wants a »really always on top, even atop other always on top windows« setting – which naturally can't exist.